# Good Hess's Law experiment

Tags: enthalpy, heat, reaction-control

I am doing an Internal Assessment for my IB chemistry class, and I want to do something on Hess's Law, and I'll be doing it simulation based, using [this](http://chemcollective.org/vlab) website. With the solutions and equipment on that simulation, what is a good experiment I can do? I want to avoid doing something relatively  easy like 'finding the enthalpy change of this reaction' and proceed to do so in under 5 pages, I want something a bit more advanced, but still able to be done on this simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do a formation of a salt using an acid/base reaction, evaporate it, then calculate the heat released when it enters solution. Extra points if you can explain heat lost to the solution in terms of the thermal stability of water.

This would give you a more advanced look into the thermal processes of chemistry, its the kind of lab we would do in Analytical Chemistry. Multiple steps of synthesis and measurement.